# C++, порядок инициализации полей класса с разным уровнем доступа

Tags: c++, инициализация

Мне известно, что конструкторы полей класса вызываются в порядке объявления этих самых полей в теле класса.

Мне также известно, что порядок следования полей класса соответствует порядку объявления лишь для полей с одинаковым уровнем доступа.

Но я совершенно не понимаю следующего:

1. Соответствует ли порядок вызова конструкторов полей порядку размещения полей в памяти?
2. Если поля имеют разный уровень доступа, то в каком порядке они конструируются? Ведь иногда бывает необходимо, чтобы сначала сконструировалось поле `а`, а потом это поле передалось в конструктор поля `b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Нестатические] поля класса инициализируются в том порядке, в котором они объявлены в определении класса. Спецификаторы доступа никак не влияют на этот порядок.

http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#13.3

Таким образом, теоретически, порядок инициализации полей может не соответствовать порядку размещения этих полей в памяти.

Comment: То есть, для `NoNPOD` типов порядок полей в памяти может не соответствовать порядку объявления, но порядок инициализации всегда соответствует порядку объявления, вне зависимости от уровня доступа?